# add javaScript array in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

i got javaScript array hold elements records with unique elementIndex in it now what I have to add single or multiple components in same javaScript array for that particular element (same elementIdex).

this array can have as many elements as required and each element may have one or multiple components associated to that element.

I have managed to do first part, how i do second part ... that is add components records associated to single element.

note element and component are in separate javaScript function but i have global array

this is what i want to achieve (may be JSON)

```
   QualificationElemenetsAndComponents[0] = {

         Element [
                 ElementIndex : "",
                 ElementMarkingSchemeTitle : "",
                 ElementAvailableMark: "",
                 ElementPassMark: "",
                 ElementDistinctionMark: "",
                 Component[0]= [ 
                               componentIndex="", 
                               componentMark =""
                               ], 
                 Component[1]= [ 
                               componentIndex="", 
                               componentMark =""
                               ], 
                 Component[2]= [ 
                               componentIndex="", 
                               componentMark =""
                               ], 
                    }
```

### global array

```
 var selectedComponentList = [];

 var selectElementList = [];
```

### element

```
  $("#ElementTable").on("click", ".k1-grid-confirm", function () {

        var E_RecordId = $(this).data("id");
        var E_MarkingSchemeTitle = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_EMST").val();
        var E_AvailableMark = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_AM").val();
        var E_PassMark = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_PM").val();
        var E_MeritMark = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_MM").val();
        var E_DistinctionMark = $("#" + E_RecordId + "_DM").val();

        alert("elementRecordId " + E_RecordId + " E_MarkingSchemeTitle " + E_MarkingSchemeTitle + " E_AvailableMark " + E_AvailableMark + " E_PassMark " + E_PassMark + " E_MeritMark " + E_MeritMark + " E_DistinctionMark " + E_DistinctionMark);

        //add data to array//

        selectElementList.push({ ElementIndex: E_RecordId, ElementMarkingSchemeTitle: E_MarkingSchemeTitle, ElementAvailableMark: E_AvailableMark, ElementPassMark: E_PassMark, ElementMeritMark: E_MeritMark, ElementDistinctionMark: E_DistinctionMark });

        }
    });
```

### Component

```
$("#ComponentSchemeTable").on("click", ".k-grid-confirm", function () {

        var recordId = $(this).data("id");
        var ComponentSchemeMark = $("#" + recordId + "_CM").val();
       //
        $(this).hide();

        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-input").hide();

        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-cancel").hide();

        $(this).siblings(".k-grid-Remove").show();

        //add data to array//
        selectedComponentList.push({ componentIndex: recordId, componentMark: ComponentSchemeMark });

         //push array to Selected Element

              ?????????????????????????????????????
        }
    });
```

Many thanks

Comment: I think he's trying to put the second array inside an object found in the first array, so push won't work. I'm not really sure about what he's trying to achieve

Comment: @JonasGrumann I am also unsure. Maybe he wants to convert `[1, [2, 3]]` to `[1, 2, 3]` or something like that?

Comment: i have updated my question and put example array of how i want to achieve data listed

Answer (score 1):

Define a function to refresh the global list:

```
// Elements
selectElementList.push({...});
refreshGlobalList();

// Components
selectedComponentList.push({...});
refreshGlobalList();
```

And the function:

```
var globalList = [];
function refreshGlobalList() {
  globalList = selectElementList.concat(selectedComponentList);
}
```

Comment: i have updated my question and listed array example, is your proposed method achieve that? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayNum.push.apply(arrayNum, arrayValuTwo);
arrayNum.push.apply(arrayNum, arrayValuThree);
```

you can try this or you can try this

```
arrayNumber.push.apply(arrayNumber, arrayValueTwo.concat(arrayValueThree));
```